# How to register 2 Browser Helper Object dlls at once into IE11 with EPM on Windows7(x64)?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, dll, windows-7-x64, bho

I made a Browser Helper object for IE11 with Enhanced Protected Mode(EPM) on/off.

In order to support compatibility, I made two BHO dll files.
One is for 32bit and the other is for 64bit. 
And I'm trying to install these dll files at once with using a cab file that has .inf as below. But I can't do it.

When I tried to install these files into IE11(with EPM on), the only dll file for 64bit was installed and BHO did not run.
And when I tried to install these files into IE11(with EPM off), the only dll file for 32bit was installed and it run.

I think that it is necessary to install 32bit dll and 64bit dll with EPM on.

Could you please let me know how to install these dll files at once into IE11 with EPM on?

Here is my .inf file.

---

```
[Version]
    Signature="$CHICAGO$"
    AdvancedINF=2.0
[Add.Code]
    MyTestBHO.dll=MyTestBHO.dll
    MyTestBHO64.dll=MyTestBHO64.dll
[Deployment]
    InstallScope=machine
[MyTestBHO.dll]
    file-win32-x86=thiscab
    file-win32-amd64=thiscab
    clsid={9576-2234-4774-80D3-1113DF081221}
    FileVersion=1,0,0,0
    RegisterServer=yes
[MyTestBHO64.dll]
    file-win32-x86=ignore
    file-win32-amd64=thiscab
    clsid={9576-2234-4774-80D3-1113DF081221}
    FileVersion=1,0,0,0
    RegisterServer=yes
```

---

Best Regards,
Kamakuran

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not whether EPM is on or off, the issue is that your BHOs should be of the same bitness as IE. So if you're running IE11 64bit, then you need to install the 64-bit version of your BHO

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/05/29/q-a-64-bit-internet-explorer.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: Yes, I have already tried to install the 64-bit version of my BHO (MyTestBHO64.dll). But MyBHO was refused as "It is not compatible with Internet Security" and Add-on Manager Window said "State is No Compatible", "Architecture is 32bit".

Comment: have you registered it with x64 bit regasm?

Comment: Sorry, I send incomplete comment.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried to install the 64-bit version of my BHO (MyTestBHO64.dll). But MyBHO was refused as "It is not compatible with Internet Explorer Security function." and Add-on Manager Window said "State is No Compatible", "Architecture is 64bit". However, if I installed the 32-bit version of my BHO (MyTestBHO.dll) manually using "regsvr32" command after installing the 64-bit version, the my BHO could run. The Add-on Manager Window said "State is Enable" and "Architecture is 32-bit and 64-bit."
So I would like to install the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version BHO at once with cab.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the 64-bit version of regsvr32 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747 so please try to register your 64bit BHO using your 64bit regsvr32 and install in your 64bit IE

Comment: I tried the command "C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe MyBHO64.dll" and it was successful. But IE Add-on Manager Window said "Architecture is 64bit", "State is no compatible"...